# Selenium Java with TestNG, insert text into Screenshot taken for failures

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have scripts written in Java Selenium with testNG framework. I could take screenshots on failures. How can I show an alert message (like JoptionPane, ...) to define the problem in some words to explain the error to anyone executes the suit and include this alert message in the taken screenshot?

Comment: Is it necessary to show an alert? What is the problem with the test output in the `test-output/` folder?

Comment: anyone who is not a programmer can run the suite, in case the suit fail, he/she can verify the problem using the screenshots , Unfortunately this is according to the system specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ImageIO** library (built-in java library) to add text (reason for failure) to the screenshots.

Note: add this logic where screenshot code is present in your framework.

Following code worked for me:

```
@org.testng.annotations.Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("inside test");
        open("https://www.google.co.in/");

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("/Users/naveen/Desktop/screenshot1.png"));
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/naveen/Desktop/screenshot1.png"));
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 100, 100);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("/Users/naveen/Desktop/test1.png"));
    }
```

Here, you can parameterise `hello world!` with assertion reason in case of failure.

Also, replace file paths with parameter.